# SSAE 16 website Audit

Tags: audit

Our client need to get our website audited for security SSAE-16. I am not aware of much about this SSAE-16. So, my question is, What areas got covered in this audit? I read some where, that it mostly relevant for data centers. Do, they need to audit website too? If yes, then what is the process and requirements of auditing the website?

Comment: it is basically the successor of SAS 70 standard...

Answer (score 0):

SSAE 16 is intended to report on controls relevant to a customer's financial statement audit. SSAE 16 has no pre-defined controls criteria like ISO 27001 or PCI-DSS.  The controls that get tested are determined and defined by the service organization.  SSAE 16 is NOT primarily intended for data centers, however, because of the history of SAS 70, many data centers still obtain an SSAE 16 report.  There are other attestation reports that may be more appropriate depending on the type of service your website provides.  I would recommend going to the AICPA website, http//www.aicpa.org/soc to get a better understanding of what you need, then talk to a reputable CPA firm for additional guidance.